# Do non-trivial kernels of maps between free modules always contain a basis element?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $f: R^m \rightarrow R^n$ a homomorphism of $R$-modules with $m>n$. Then does there exist a basis $x_1,\cdots , x_m$ of $R^m$ such that $f(x_1)=0$?
What if we further assume that $R$ is local? In the non-local case, a special question would be if $M\subset R^{t+d}$ is a stably free module of type $t$ and rank $d>1$, must $M$ contain a basis element of $R^{t+d}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R = k[x, y]$ for $k$ a field, let $m = 2, n = 1$, and let $f : R^2 \to R$ be given by

$$f(a, b) = xa + by \in R.$$

Then $\text{ker}(f)$ is generated by $(-y, x)$ which cannot be an element of any basis, nor can any multiple of it, because it's contained in the image of a nontrivial ideal $m = (x, y)$ of $R$. This counterexample continues to work after localizing at $m$, so it doesn't help to assume that $R$ is local.

Here's a sketch: a vector $v_1 \in R^n$ is an element of a basis iff it's the first column of a matrix in $GL_n(R)$, hence iff we can find $v_2, \dots v_n \in R^n$ such that the matrix with columns $v_1, \dots v_n$ has invertible determinant. If the entries of $v_1$ are entirely contained in a proper ideal $I \subsetneq R$ then so is this determinant, so it can't be invertible. Equivalently, regarding this determinant as a linear combination of the entries of $v_1$ using the entries of $v_2, \dots v_n$, we see that the existence of such a determinant implies that the entries of $v_1$ generate the unit ideal in $R$.

---

**Edit:** In the comments you ask what happens if $f$ is assumed to be surjective and I mentioned that in this case $\text{ker}(f)$ is a stably free module. Here we can use [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/stablyfree.pdf)'s example of a stably free module which is not free: let $R = \mathbb{R}[x, y, z]/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1)$ be the ring of polynomial functions on the 2-sphere $S^2$ and let $f : R^3 \to R$ be given by

$$f(a, b, c) = xa + by + cz \in R.$$

Then $\text{ker}(f)$ is the module of polynomial vector fields on $S^2$. By the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem), any such vector field vanishes at some point $p \in S^2$, so the corresponding maximal ideal $m_p$ can be used as in the above argument to show that no element of $\text{ker}(f)$ can be part of a basis of $R^3$.

Comment: Thank you. So here's the problem from which the present question originates. Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over $R$. If $\mu(M)$ is the smallest integer $r\ge 0$ such that $M$ can be generated by $r$ elements, then any linearly independent set of $M$ cannot contain more than $\mu(M)$ elements. If $R$ is local, by Nakayama's lemma, all minimal generating sets of $M$ contain exactly $\mu(M)$ elements. Now i was wondering if any two linearly independent sets of $M$ contain the same number of elements and whether the answer depends on $R$ being local or not?

Comment: By the way, does the answer to the original question change if the map $f$ is assumed to be surjective?

Comment: @sagnik: I assume you mean whether any two *maximal* linearly independent subsets of $M$ contain the same number of elements. Apparently this is true if $R$ is either noetherian or an integral domain but false in general: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33294/cardinal-of-maximal-linearly-independent-subsets-of-a-free-module

Comment: If $f$ is assumed to be surjective then the short exact sequence $0 \to \text{ker}(f) \to R^m \to R^n \to 0$ splits and $\text{ker}(f)$ is some stably free direct summand of $R^m$, and in particular is projective. I think this rules out a counterexample like the one I used above. I don't know what happens in this case off the top of my head.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it's maximal, i was about to correct it. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: Since ker$(f)$ is stably free, locally it contains a basis element. So the question is whether we can lift it to a `global basis element'.

Comment: @sagnik: there is still a counterexample if $f$ is surjective and the same idea works, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice topological argument.